# Writing directly to the HDMI display

Tags: hdmi, display

I would like to boot a Rasperry Pi in headless mode and then use a notebook-sized monochrome LCD display attached to the HDMI port as a DIRECT output device, bypassing the OS. In particular, I would like text labels and numeric data to appear in fixed locations on the screen with the ability to regularly update the numeric data by writing to that location from a Python program  (this will be a text-based instrument panel for an experimental home-built airplane).  It seems like a simple and obvious thing to do, but I have been unable to find any clues how to do it.  Most references I have found to directly writable LCDs are for 40x2 (or smaller) character displays, whereas I need considerably more real estate for displaying multiple variables simultaneously (possibly some simple graphics too, but I can live without it if necessary).

I would consider an arrangement in which the OS *does* share the monitor, but only if it can be made to completely disappear after the program is started, ensuring direct and exclusive access to the screen for the aforementioned real-time display.

In the old days working with an IBM/DOS computer, I could control the non-windowed screen display very simply by poking characters or bit data into specific physical memory addresses. I'm basically trying to find a way to achieve equivalent functionality with today's hardware, presumably through a layer of software that knows how to talk to the hardware. Sample pseudocode:

```
  1   open screen device on HDMI port and set any relevant modes
  2   specify a starting screen address (row and character no.) and write a
      N-character string to that location
  3   repeat
```

Any pointers?

Comment: In the old days with IBM/DOS there was a memory region which was directly mapped to the display screen and by poking bytes into the memory region you could change the displayed text. Why do you want to do something similar? Are you concerned about the speed of the display updates and text changes? Or what other reasons do you have for wanting this particular approach.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like http://www.ummon.eu/Linux/API/Devices/framebuffer.html or perhaps http://betteros.org/tut/graphics1.php or perhaps this https://01.org/blogs/2016/sharing-cpu-and-gpu-buffers-linux  or perhaps this https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~joshagam/archive/cs574/3-dri.html  or this https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt or this http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Zero-Copy%20Display%20of%20Guest%20Framebuffers%20using%20GEM.pdf and frankly it all seems to be a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

After seeking advice in a number of venues, both online and offline, and running into mostly dead ends, I ended up deciding that my best option was NOT to try to separate the display from OS control and write to it using a low-level interface, as that seemed to be fraught with complexities.

Rather, it satisfies the intent of my question (if not the details) to run a program that would launch on boot, open in full-screen mode and simply cover up everything else until the program terminated.

For that purpose, the Tkinter/Canvas module for Python seems to offer the "friendliest" environment for not only creating the full-screen window but also writing arbitrary text and simple graphics to arbitrary locations on the screen. It's much easier to use than any alternative I have seen so far.

A minimal working example was posted here by someone else:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856817/tkinter-canvas-based-kiosk-like-program-for-raspberry-pi

I have already found that I can do pretty much everything I wanted to do starting with that example.

Answer (score 2):

What I *think* you mean is that you do not want to have a GUI running on the HDMI display.  You will instead turn off any local logins on the *console* and then run an application, probably with the [NCurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library which provides the sort of low-level CLI interface that you desire except that you use functions that produce the display desired into the buffers that it provides.  *NCurses* role in this is to provide an abstraction so that the content is transferred to the display hardware (or framebuffer) in as fast and efficient manner as possible - what- and where-ever that hardware is...

There are also parts that handle getting input from the user and you could make it easier to test and construct by doing it as a program that runs from the *text* login console and eventually prevent it from exiting and prevent the `Alt-F` key-presses that normally cause **V**irtual **T**ermnal switching.

Comment: I think the question needs to be updated with an explanation as to whether there are real time display changes required so that if the airplane is changing altitude rapidly or heading rapidly the display status can be in real time and synchronous with real world events. Not sure how much overhead and delay would come from NCurses and a terminal window.

Comment: Regarding SlySven's comment: I'm aware of ncurses and have thought about it as a solution to my problem. What I'm not clear on is whether I could have a remote login to the Pi for general interaction with the OS while letting ncurses take control of the physically attached monitor.

Regarding RC's comment:  I don't think the overhead and delay would be too significant, as long as no process comes along and suspends or blocks the ncurses output for more than a second or two.

Also, unless I'm mistaken, ncurses does not support any kind of graphic output to the screen.

Comment: It seems that one possible way to get to where I want to be is to run the Pi with a browser in kiosk mode and then figure out a way to display the data I want in the browers (with automatic real-time updates).

https://www.danpurdy.co.uk/web-development/raspberry-pi-kiosk-screen-tutorial/

Comment: Well, yeah, you could run a GUI on an xserver (look into using `xinit(1)` with your application run as the client program ___instead___ of a window manager) - I understand a `tcl/tk` combination may be something that could provided you with the sort of widgets you want...